# Extracting a list of unique text cells from a large, wide, headerless, mixed format table

Tags: excel

It should be a quickie to VBA/Excel experts. I have a large 60 to 2000 rows, wide 10,000 columns, table without headers in Excel, with the following format.

```
+---------+----------------+------------------+----------+
|         |    20110811    |      20110810    |  20110810|
+---------+----------------+------------------+----------+
| AA UN   | 4.0111         |  AA UN           |   5.0222 |
| AXP UN  | 3.0611         |  AXP UN          |   3.0217 |
| BA UN   | 3.997          |  BA UN           |   4.0532 |
| BAC UN  | 0.4924         |  BAC UN          |   0.478  |
| CAT UN  | 5.9259         |  CAT UN          |   5.8959 |
| CSCO UW | 1.0813         |  CSCO UW         |   0.9693 |
| CVX UN  | 6.3891         |  CVX UN          |   6.3943 |
| DD UN   | 3.1894         |  DD UN           |   3.165  |
| DIS UN  | 2.1815         |  DIS UN          |   2.2267 |
| GE UN   | 1.065          |  GE UN           |   1.0654 |
+---------+----------------+------------------+----------+
```

The question is how to get a unique list of text cells out from the whole table, I have been playing with advanced autofilter but it really doesnt give what i want. Im looking for smth like that below

```
╔═════════╗
║ AA UN   ║
║ AXP UN  ║
║ BA UN   ║
║ BAC UN  ║
║ CAT UN  ║
║ CSCO UW ║
║ CVX UN  ║
║ DD UN   ║
║ DIS UN  ║
║ GE UN   ║
╚═════════╝
```

Btw, thanks to GSerg for formatting, now i learnt a new trick

Comment: How are you looking to get the list back? A single cell with all values linebreak-separated? On a separate sheet in a single column list?

Comment: @Issun, Could be same sheet or a different sheet as a column of cells with each text ( basically a 1-3 word string) in its cell. The original text in the table is in that form - a 1-3 word string in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to dump the entire range into a variable array and then loop through it adding entries that aren't numbers into a dictionary object. That will eliminate all dupes and non-numeric data. Take the dictionary keys and transpose them back on the sheet.

**UPDATE**:
Here is code you can use.

**How it works**: You'll can adjust the range (right now it's all cells used), but it will dump every cell into a variant array in one shot. Then it goes through the array (much faster than going through cells) and if the entry is not empty, nor numeric, it adds it to a dictionary object. Since you can't put 2 keys that are the same into a dictionary, it just skips over all dupes automatically. Then I paste the unique list into sheet2 (you can adjust this as well).

```vb
Sub UniqueTextList()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

vArray = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value    
For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        If Len(vArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(vArray(i, j)) = False Then
                dictionary(vArray(i, j)) = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheet2.range("a1").Resize(dictionary.count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dictionary.keys)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox dictionary.Count & " unique cell(s) were found and copied."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Interesting! I have no idea whatsoever how to approach this though :( . I work in R/SAS/Stata but even there it would be somewhat of a nontrivial task and converting back and from xls has to be done manually

Comment: If I can get to a pc in the next day or so I'll update with code you can use :)

Comment: testing this right now, first tests crashed excel, but i think it works now. It also extract all the number and adds all the txt at the end of the vector. Smth like this   BHI UN
14.89680556
15.07769676
15.05609954
15.1887037
15.28409722
CAM UN
BJS UN
DO UN
ESV UN
EXH UN
HAL UN
NBR UN
GRP UN
NE UN mmmm i dont know how to do the carriage return in the post window, enter seems to save the message. Anyway, mate, thanks a lot!!!! This is now doable and i think it gets out all of the unique texts, even with numbers its much easier now to copy paste and create the text list

Comment: That's unusual, maybe your numeric cells are formatted as text in which case the numbers would be included.

Comment: A work around if the numbers are formatted as text is to change the IsNumeric is to do an instr and look for a period.

Comment: sorry for stream of consciousness post :) carriage return - i referred to the post window on SO, can't format it the way i want to. Most likely the numbers are also formatted as text, the table is a result of proprietary query run through an excel add in, so i can't really control the output or the formatting of the cells.

Comment: I don't really know how to do instr and look for a period. Some sort of a nested search func that would if/else if the cell has a period? Anyway, this was enormously helpful! thanks a lot mate! dont have enough rep to +1 tho :(

Comment: No prob! Please accept the answer by selecting the arrow mark that appears at the upper left of the answer  if this has been helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

My [Duplicate Master addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2123.html) uses a similar approach to Issun

While the bulk of the functionality is aimed as dupes it includes option to extract

1. Uniques (data that occurs at least once), or
2. True Uniques (data that only occurs once)

And it can find uniques as single cells (your case), complete rows, or as a mix of columns

Lastly it has options to

- ignore all whitespaces (including CHAR 160)
- ignore Case
- apply `TRIM` and/or `CLEAN` functions
- Regexp string substitions